# Finite Subgroups of SO(3) are conjugate if and only if they are isomorphic [reference request]

Tags: reference-request, euclidean-geometry, crystallography

It says [here](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Classification_of_finite_subgroups_of_SO(3,R)#Fallout_implications) that any two isomorphic finite subgroups of $\mathrm{SO}(3)$ are conjugate. Does anyone have a published reference for this fact? The link says that it's a 'fallout implication' of the classification of such finite subgroups.